# Can we have fewer featured questions on Meta? I am not seeing hot Meta posts anymore

Tags: discussion

There is a field in the top right corner of any Travel SE site (most of the times) that shows four **HOT META POSTS** and featured posts on Meta. Right now all four of these spots are filled up with [featured posts](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured).
Can we free those spots?

[image]

I'm not regularly checking Meta and I like how this box made me aware of new discussions there. Featured posts are fine but they should not be blocking the actual Meta for weeks in a row. At least leave two open spots and rotate a bit more through featured status. (Personally I also think the featured posts have now been seen by those who care and most if not all of them can be un-featured, but this is not what I want this post to be about.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Done. Only 2 posts are now featured. I can't guarantee it will always stay at 2, but it's reasonable to only limit ourselves to a few at a time.

Comment: @mts funnily enough your own post is now taking up a featured spot :)

Comment: Yep, your solution apparently worked as this q/a now shows up in Hot Meta Posts.